# What does this line of Ruby/Rails do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Can you please walk me through the following line of Ruby/Rails?

```
if user.role? :super_admin
```

To fit my app, I updated it to:

```
if user.role? :admin
```

and that failed, but then I updated it to:

```
if user.role? == 'admin'
```

And it works as intended. Why is that?

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :super_admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :product_admin
      can :manage, [Product, Asset, Issue]
    elsif user.role? :product_team
      can :read, [Product, Asset]
      # manage products, assets he owns
      can :manage, Product do |product|
        product.try(:owner) == user
      end
      can :manage, Asset do |asset|
        asset.assetable.try(:owner) == user
      end
    end
  end
end



def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @TheAppre What is the class of `user`?

Comment: You need to post the source of the user class (esp. the role? method) to be able to tell for sure. methods ending with a '?' by convention return true or false but they can return anything. In this case it looks like it's returning the role name rather than accepting an argument and saying t/f if the user has that role.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm following the tutorial here: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

Comment: Can you provide the text of the error message as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if user.role? :super_admin
```

In this line you call the method `role?` on the object `user` with the parameter `:super_admin` (which is a [symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html)) and check if the method returns `true`.

If the call to `user.role? :admin` returns false there might simply be no role named '*admin*'.

Reading CanCan's documentation on [Role Based Authorization](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/role-based-authorization) should shed some light on this subject.